# Need to send email in background using Ionic/Cordova for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, email, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app in **Ionic/Cordova** for us by iOs and Android smartphone users.  As part of the app, I want to build and send an email in the background (i.e, no email editor display).  I've researched extensively and found no way to use the standard *ngcordova* email plugin for this.  Can anyone point me to a solution that will facilitate using just one Ionic/Cordova project to build an iOs and an Android app?

Comment: hey @Nikola , did you found solution for this, i am having same problem, i dont want to use php REST service for this.

Comment: That is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is that from your Ionic application you call a REST service on your server which then takes care of email sending.

For example, a simple mail() command (if you're using PHP on your server for the service implementation) would do just fine if your server is on Linux. Also, you could then (from the service) call some other third party mail sending provider like for example Mandril.